# Delete VSTS builds using the OAuth Token

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

With the new possibility to get the OAuth token to access the VSTS API during a build, I tried to write a script which deletes certain builds.

Reading builds works fine like this:

```
$headers = @{  Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }
$baseUrl = "{0}{1}" -f $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI, $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID
$buildsUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0", $baseUrl)
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $buildsUrl -Headers $headers
```

But while trying to delete a build I get a **403 Forbidden** error:

```
$deleteUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/build/builds/{1}?api-version=2.0", $baseUrl, $id)
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Delete
```

Is deleting just not possible with the OAuth token provided by VSTS to the build or do I need to call the delete request differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a security issue. The build service account does not have the permission to "Delete Builds" by default. Set the permission to "Allow" and then try again.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Eddie. When trying to change the `Delete builds` permission on the build definition I get the following error `VSS012010: Invalid User Id: 1c8ede55-4f4d-40e6-8038-7b4cfc94db64. Service Identity is not allowed.` (for Project Build Service and Project Collection Build Service). After closing the dialog and reopening it seems to be still saved, but while running the build it makes no difference.

Comment: @PascalBerger I just did a quick test with your code. I get the same error message as you when set the delete build permission. But the build can be deleted successfully during the build process.

Comment: @PascalBerger I set the permission for this account: Project Collection Build Service (MyAccountName).

Comment: I've also set "Project Collection Build Service (MyAccountName)" "Delete builds" to "Allow". But still get the 403 Forbidden. 

You also use the same request, header values, etc for deleting the build, as described above in the question?

Comment: @PascalBerger Yes, I just copy and paste your code in powershell and run it. The only changes is "-Uri $url" to "-Uri $deleteUrl" what I think is a typo in you question. By the way, when you set the permission, are you select "All build definitions" to set the security?

Comment: I set the permission using the context menu on the build definition | Security.

Comment: @PascalBerger Context menu for just one build definition or "All build definitions"? See the image in my answer for details.

Comment: Ah, that did it. If I set all for "All build definitions" it works, before I tried to just a specific definition. Thank you!

There seems to be several bug involved with this (Error message, Permissions not working on specific build definition). Are you reporting them internally or should I report them?

Comment: @PascalBerger When you just set a specific definition, you need to set the security permission for the definition that the build you want to delete belong. I ask you to set the permission for all definitions is because I don't know how many definitions is related to the builds you want to delete.

Comment: I relates only to one definition. But setting the permission on the definition doesn't work. Setting it for all build definitions worked. And on both of them I get the error message while saving the changes, even though they seems to be saved correctly.

Comment: @PascalBerger Oh, I didn't see the definition permission issue at my side. You can report these issues to MS. :)